# Gradle skipping distZip task from distribution plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using Gradle 1.6 to build a library I wrote. I am trying to create an uber zip file that contains my jar and several other 3rd Party dependencies of this jar. If I apply the `distribution` plugin and run any of the distZip/distTar/installDist tasks, gradle skips those tasks and says they are UP-TO-DATE. No uber archive gets created. Instead of applying  `distribution` if I apply the `application` plugin and give it a `mainClassName` attribute then gradle builds the uber archive just fine. Is there something that I am not doing with the `distribution` plugin? Why is it refusing to build the uber archive?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you haven't configured the distribution plugin correctly. For example, perhaps you haven't declared the contents of the distribution. For details, see the distribution plugin chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the samples in the full Gradle distribution.

PS: Please always show the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I haven't done any configurations related to the distribution plugin in the gradle file, other than `apply distribution`. I was of the idea the jar I am building along with its dependencies get included into the uber archive by default without having to explicitly specify what the contents if the archive are. Is that correct?

Comment: No, that's not correct. You have to explicitly declare the contents of the distribution, as explained in the user guide. Perhaps you are looking for the "Java Library Distribution Plugin".